# Indirect __iadd__ method combined with __setitem__

Tags: python, magic-methods

I have something like this:

```
 class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
       self.bar = ...

    def __setitem__(self, key, value=None) :
       self.bar[key] = value
```

Now I want:

```
  f = Foo()
  f['shmoo'] += 5
```

to do:

```
  f.bar['shmoo'] += 5
```

there is:

```
  def __iadd__(self,other): .....
```

but there the 'key' is not available. Any way to solve this?

Comment: Implement `__getitem__`? `f['shmoo'] += 5` doesn't invoke `Foo#__iadd__`, it's `f['shmoo'] = f['shmoo'] + 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.['shmoo'] += 5` does the augmented assignment operation on the value in the collection (`f.['shmoo']`), not the collection itself. The pseudocode is

```
val = f.__getitem__('shmoo')
val += 5
f.__setitem('shmoo', val)
```

Implement `__getitem__` but there is no need to implememnt `__iadd__` and friends.

We can demonstrate by adding some prints to Foo and creating a new class for the value.

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = {}

    def __getitem__(self, name):
        print("foo get", name)
        return self.bar[name]

    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        print('foo set', name, value)
        self.bar[name] = value

class Baz:

    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.val = self.val + other
        print("baz iadd", other, self.val)
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)
```

Running, the sequence of events is

```
assign
foo set a 0
augmented addition
foo get a
baz iadd 2 2
foo set a 2
```

Comment: so u saying  setitem() gets the already summed  value. i just have  to set-it-out

Comment: Yes... first python does a `__getitem__` then a `__setitem__`. It would fail for your simple example because you don't have a `__getitem__`, of course.